# Defining an environment that leaves the surrounding environment

Tags: environments

I'd like to define an environment like this:

```
\newenvironment{antiitemize}{\end{itemize}}{\begin{itemize}}
```

I call it `antiitemize` because I intend to use it inside an `itemize` environment to break out of the list for a short while, e.g. to write a comment that's not really part of the list. For instance, I would like to write

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{antiitemize}{\end{itemize}}{\begin{itemize}}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

Donec aliquam quam sed enim bibendum, quis ultrices felis porttitor.

\begin{itemize}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\item Quisque ac porttitor lectus.

\begin{antiitemize}
Mauris a libero laoreet, iaculis arcu et, tincidunt quam.
\end{antiitemize}

\item Suspendisse auctor leo ut felis lobortis commodo vel quis diam.

\end{itemize}

Morbi nec rhoncus ante.

\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work. LaTeX seems not to like that the environments are ill-nested. I've found a work-around that involves defining a pair of commands to start and end the `antiitemize` environment manually, like so.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\antiitemize{\end{itemize}}
\def\endantiitemize{\begin{itemize}}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

Donec aliquam quam sed enim bibendum, quis ultrices felis porttitor.

\begin{itemize}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\item Quisque ac porttitor lectus.

\antiitemize
Mauris a libero laoreet, iaculis arcu et, tincidunt quam.
\endantiitemize

\item Suspendisse auctor leo ut felis lobortis commodo vel quis diam.

\end{itemize}

Morbi nec rhoncus ante.

\end{document}
```

This is tolerable, but I'd really like to know why I can't define my `antiitemize` environment using `\newenvironment`.

---

**Edit.** In response to some of the comments my question has received, here are a couple of notes about my motivation for asking this question.

- cgnieder points out that `\end{itemize}...\begin{itemize}` would have the same effect as `\begin{antiitemize}...\end{antiitemize}`. This is true, but in my use case it's not a very 'semantic' way to do the document mark up. The stuff in my `antiitemize` environment should be thought of as 'an interruption in the list' rather than as 'ending one list and starting another'.
- I didn't make this clear in my original question, but I guess what I'd really like an answer to is: *why* is my `antiitemize` environment broken?

Comment: You can use the package `enumitem` and the option resume. However I can't see any benefit for your declaration especially for a simple `itemize` environment.

Comment: Where is the advantage of typing `\begin{antiitemize}` instead of `\end{itemize}` (and vice versa)?

Comment: I'll just leave this here (accessible only to TUG members until about 9 mo have passed): https://www.tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109hunt.pdf

Comment: mark wooding write a thing called `mdwlist.sty`, which includes `\suspend` and `\resume` commands, for doing “non-list” insertions into `itemize` (and the like) lists.  look for the `mdwtools` directory on ctan.

Comment: @cgnieder Good point. Your suggestion would have the same effect, but it wouldn't be so *semantic*, if you know what I mean. I've updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Maybe you should describe your actual use case then?

Comment: @cgnieder My use case is that the `itemize` environment represents some sort of 'source code', and my `antiitemize` environment represents how I'd like to format certain 'comments' that appear within the source code. I should also mention that the `.tex` file is automatically generated from the source code. So I really want to markup my document with a single `itemize` environment (to represent the entire source code) and then periodically break out of this environment temporarily in order to format a comment. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You already can do that quite easily with the `enumitem` package: it has a `resume*` option that uses the parameters of the preceding list of the same type and level, and, for `enumerate`, starts the counter where the preceding list had left it. Demo:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

Donec aliquam quam sed enim bibendum, quis ultrices felis porttitor.

\begin{itemize}[label =\color{VioletRed}$ \lozenge $]

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\item Quisque ac porttitor lectus.

\end{itemize}
Mauris a libero laoreet, iaculis arcu et, tincidunt quam.

\begin{itemize}[resume*]

\item Suspendisse auctor leo ut felis lobortis commodo vel quis diam.

\end{itemize}

Morbi nec rhoncus ante.

\begin{itemize}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\item Quisque ac porttitor lectus.

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where's the point in resuming an `itemize` list? The output without the option is the same as with it (except if you do the local label redefinition like in your example which IMHO is conceptually wrong and should go into the preamble even if one wants two different `itemize` lists)

Comment: Yes but it can be used with special values of parameters. It saves writing the same optional arguments again and again. I agree it's more useful for  `enumerate`. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: But if you have a special kind of list the way to go IMHO is to define a new list in the preamble and use that one in the document instead. And then resuming of the list is pointless. (And the question of the OP (how to leave the surrounding environment) then still isn't solved...)

Comment: Certainly, albeit it may depend on the number of such lists one has to write.

Comment: Maybe... I for my part (nearly) *always* define new environments/commands for this. I like my document to be completely semantic. The “nearly” part has bitten me more than once already... I'm working on it to eliminate it :)

Comment: I completely share your opinion about semantics, the problem being in some cases to determine what is really semantic, and what is purely occasional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16561/discussion-between-cgnieder-and-bernard).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\antiitemize`  and `\endantiitemize` in place of `\begin{antiitemize}` and `\end{antiitemize}`, and keep the environment definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{antiitemize}{\end{itemize}}{\begin{itemize}}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

Donec aliquam quam sed enim bibendum, quis ultrices felis porttitor.

\begin{itemize}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\item Quisque ac porttitor lectus.

\antiitemize

Mauris a libero laoreet, iaculis arcu et, tincidunt quam.

\endantiitemize

\item Suspendisse auctor leo ut felis lobortis commodo vel quis diam.

\end{itemize}

Morbi nec rhoncus ante.

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the results [here](https://www.writelatex.com/read/mrrvrfypdzwk).

Comment: This is shown in the second example of the original post.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel the second example shows an explicit definition for `\antiitemize` and `\endantiitemize`. I propose to use their implicit definition, by maintaining the `\newenvironment{antiitemize}` command.

Comment: Why not the other way around `\newenvironment{antiitemize}{\enditemize}{\itemize}` and then use `\begin{antiitemize}` and `\end{antiitemize}`.

Comment: @Manuel you could try it yourself to see why :)

Comment: @Manuel indeed, that would work too.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon try it: it doesn't. While it gives no error the “escaped” paragraph is indented like it was still in an `itemize` environment

Comment: @cgnieder my bad, I didn't notice that difference!

Comment: @cgnieder True, I didn't try it. However it defies my logic, shouldn't it work as I expected? (I mean “is the definition of `\itemize` and `\enditemize` as correct as it could be?”.)